# How to catch F1 and F2 in windows mobile 6?

Tags: windows-mobile-6

how can I catch F2 and F1 in my device?

I have to use it in my application but it doesnt work

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you are a C/C++ programmer all you need to do is call AllKeys(TRUE); in WinMain or your startup code.

If you are a .NET programmer, you can read the full story here: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/09/20/windows-mobile-cf-how-to-catch-f1-and-f2-in-weh/

I am sorry for providing the link only, but it is not that simple to catch F1 and F2 in .NET Compact Framework.